# CS0120 Attempting to invoke a method on a different script, but this error is produced

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to coding, so apologies if any terminology is wrong. The code is trying to change a bool from false to true (it will do something more significant later, but I'm having issues doing this which is much simpler). I'm doing this in unity if that changes anything.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimalPositionalUpdates : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PositionArrays ScripBeingAcessed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Find where the position is going to be input
        int ArrayPosition = ScripBeingAcessed.FoodPosition.Length + 1;

        PositionArrays.PositionBeingUpdated = transform.position;
     
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Second Script (the one that I'm trying to influence)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PositionArrays : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool PositionInProcess = false;
    public Vector3 PositionBeingUpdated;
    public Vector3[] FoodPosition = new Vector3[0];

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }

    public void ArrayPosUpdate()
    {
        PositionInProcess = true;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. As far as I know, there is some issue with me trying to use a static method like an instance??? Idk where it starts being static, and putting static in the method declaration for both only causes the same error to appear again referencing different components.

The error Is on line 16 of the first script.

Full error message

"CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PositionArrays.PositionBeingUpdated' 16  Active"

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? Are you sure you don't mean to use `ScripBeingAcessed.PositionBeingUpdated = transform.position;`?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much!

Comment: Did you try to do your own research? -> [Compiler Error CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are lacking fundamentals of OOP and delved into Unity development right away. You can do this, but I guess that programming in Unity will Taint your C# if you did not learn it properly. Having said that, you could certainly do it, but I'd suggest learning proper C# first and then use that sometimes uncommon Unity style.

There is some confusion around how the fields of your class are used, so let me explain: Usually, a class is a blueprint of sorts of which you can create instances. All of these instances adhere to that blueprint, which tells you exactly *how* you can use those instances (this is sometimes called implicit interface) and which data they contain (this is where Unity is somewhat sloppy). An instance bundles up the data with the methods you use to access and manipulate the data and you *"always"* need an instance to access these members, usually through a variable.

In your case, this variable is `ScripBeingAcessed`. This is the variable that holds your instance (at least if you did not forget to assign it) and therefor, you'd need the variable to access the field `PositionBeingUpdated`

```cs
void Start()
{
    //Find where the position is going to be input
    int ArrayPosition = ScripBeingAcessed.FoodPosition.Length + 1;

    ScripBeingAcessed.PositionBeingUpdated = transform.position;
}
```

#### On `static`

Besides the members of a class that form the actual blueprint to create instances from, there are members that are accessed through the class itself. These are called static members. Anyway, since they are not bound to an instance, static members that contain any data will be the same regardless of where you access them from. This may be fine, if the static members are `private` (only instances of that class can access it) but I'd avoid it otherwise, since this creates a global state, which is not safe of being manipulated from other classes and can thus lead to hard to debug errors.